# Why navicat writes key instead of foreign key in CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trl_bill` (
  `bill_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fee` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `begin_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `is_paid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bill_id`),
  KEY `request_id` (`request_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is my table sql, i use navicat to design my database, why it writes `KEY` instead of `FOREIGN KEY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KEY` keyword is a synonym for [`INDEX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) in MySQL. You do not have a [foreign key constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) specified in that [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) command.

The `CREATE TABLE` syntax:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    { LIKE old_tbl_name | (LIKE old_tbl_name) }
create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
      [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | {FULLTEXT|SPATIAL} [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
      [index_name] (index_col_name,...) reference_definition
  | CHECK (expr)
```

Comment: @kamil: I'm glad it helped. You may want to mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful. You can do this by clicking on the green tick on the left of the answer :)